# How to use ffmpeg to join MP3s and copy the metadata at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, metadata

Various pages on the Internet talk about how to use `ffmpeg` to join MP3s and copy the tags, but I cannot seem to get it to work properly. Ideally, what would happen is that it would join all the MP3s together, then take the first MP3's metadata, such as album, track, author, etc. and copy it to the final file.

I've put together the following script. While it joins the files, it does not copy the metadata. I thought the `-map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1` parameters to `ffmpeg` would do it, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <output_file> <mp3_file> <mp3_file> ..."
    exit 1
fi
output_file="$1"
shift

queue_file=$(mktemp "${PWD}/queue.XXXXXX")
for m in "$@" ; do
    echo "file '$m'" >> "${queue_file}"
done

cat "${queue_file}"
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "${queue_file}" -c copy -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "${output_file}"
rm "${queue_file}"
```

Comment: Ingest the first file only as a 2nd input i.e. `-i "${queue_file}" -i "first_file"` and and use `-map_metadata 1`.

Comment: @Gyan Would this end up getting the first file to be copied to the output file twice?

Comment: No, there are no stream maps, so ffmpeg will pick one of the inputs, and since the stream properties are the same, it'll pick the first one.